# How do I make process.argv print only the arguments (and not the path or node command)

Tags: javascript, node.js

It says it all in the title! I am making a very big project (involving AppleScript and iMessage) and the script has been tested and it opens terminal and will run: `node ~/Desktop/chatbot [argument]`. Currently, all it does is pass me this: `[ '/usr/local/bin/node', '~/Desktop/chatbot', '[argument]' ]`. How do I get it to pass me only `[argument]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I get it to pass me only [argument]?

You don't.  That's how it is designed.  You can safely just ignore the `[0]` and the `[1]` elements of that array and just start looking at `[2]`.  If you really want to make an array with those elements removed, you can `.slice(2)`:

```
let args = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(args);
```

Or if all you want is the first command line argument, you can get that directly:

```
let arg = process.argv[2];
console.log(arg);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first two arguments are always `node` and the `file/file path` that you are trying to run.

If you only want to get the arguments passed other than `node` and `file path`, just ignore the first two values and retrieve them like:

```
for(var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
  console.log(process.argv[i]);
}
```